# Converting Actionscript 1 to Actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript

Hi – can someone help with converting this Actionscript 1 to Actionscript 3

(Syntax error: expecting identifier before colon.)

```
loadMovie("leader.swf", "subHold");
lr1.gotoAndStop(1);
if (_root.links.:mlink==1) {
  play();
  _root.links.:mlink=0;
} else {
  stop();
}
```

And,
(Access of undefined property lr2)

```
lr2.gotoAndStop(1);
```

Comment: (1) Don't use any (special characters like) colon or semi-colon for names. Why not just call it `mlink` instead of this funky `:mlink`? (2) Did you ever create a MovieClip variable called `lr2`? If not, that's why it is saying "undefined" about it...

Answer (score 0):

It is your syntax:
If the MovieClips within subHold are labeled "lr2" and/or "lr1" (you seem to be using both) then just update the syntax to:

```
if (_root.links.nextFrame) {
  play();

 } else {
 stop();
}
```